# angular js infinite scrolling with django rest framework

Tags: python, angularjs, django

I've been following this tutorial here for the infinite scrolling.

http://en.proft.me/2015/09/4/how-make-infinity-scroll-loading-bar-angularjs/

but for some reason it's throwing me this error

"angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr"

am i doing something wrong here?

im a newbie to django rest framework and angular js.

what i want to achieve here is having the API json data loaded and injected into the html (which i did) and have it scrollable and clickable. (with hyperlinks, but without refreshing the page)

could anyone take a look at the code?

index.html

```
<body>

<div class="pinGridWrapper" ng-app="PinApp" ng-controller="PinCtrl">
  <div class="pinGrid" infinite-scroll='pins.more()' infinite-scroll-disabled='pins.busy' infinite-scroll-distance='1'>
    <div class="pin" ng-repeat="pin in pins.items">
                <img ng-src="{$ pin.photo $}">

  <div ng-app="myApp" class="app">
    <div ng-controller="appCtrl as vm" class="main-container">
        <h1>Post List</h1>
        {% verbatim %}
        <div ng-repeat="post in vm.posts | limitTo: 10" class="post">
        <a href="{{ post.url}}">
            <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
            <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
      </a>
            <p ng-if="vm.loadingPosts">Loading...</p>
        </div>
        {% endverbatim %}
    </div>
  </div>


      <p ng-bind-html="pin.text"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div ng-show='pins.busy'><i class="fa fa-spinner"></i></div>
</div>






<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script   src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"   integrity="sha256-lZFHibXzMHo3GGeehn1hudTAP3Sc0uKXBXAzHX1sjtk="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-route.js"></script>


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.5/marked.min.js'></script>

<script>
/* ng-infinite-scroll - v1.0.0 - 2013-02-23 */
var mod;mod=angular.module("infinite-scroll",[]),mod.directive("infiniteScroll",["$rootScope","$window","$timeout",function(i,n,e){return{link:function(t,l,o){var r,c,f,a;return n=angular.element(n),f=0,null!=o.infiniteScrollDistance&&t.$watch(o.infiniteScrollDistance,function(i){return f=parseInt(i,10)}),a=!0,r=!1,null!=o.infiniteScrollDisabled&&t.$watch(o.infiniteScrollDisabled,function(i){return a=!i,a&&r?(r=!1,c()):void 0}),c=function(){var e,c,u,d;return d=n.height()+n.scrollTop(),e=l.offset().top+l.height(),c=e-d,u=n.height()*f>=c,u&&a?i.$$phase?t.$eval(o.infiniteScroll):t.$apply(o.infiniteScroll):u?r=!0:void 0},n.on("scroll",c),t.$on("$destroy",function(){return n.off("scroll",c)}),e(function(){return o.infiniteScrollImmediateCheck?t.$eval(o.infiniteScrollImmediateCheck)?c():void 0:c()},0)}}}]);



var app = angular.module('PinApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ngResource', 'infinite-scroll']);

app.config(function($interpolateProvider, $httpProvider, cfpLoadingBarProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{$');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('$}');
    cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeSpinner = false;
});

app.factory('Pin', function($http, cfpLoadingBar){
    var Pin = function() {
        this.items = [];
        this.busy = false;
        this.url = "/api/posts/?limit=2&offset=0";
    }

    Pin.prototype.more = function() {
        if (this.busy) return;
        if (this.url) {
            this.busy = true;
            cfpLoadingBar.start();
            $http.get(this.url).success(function(data) {
                var items = data.results;
                for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    this.items.push(items[i]);
                }
                this.url = data.next;
                this.busy = false;
                cfpLoadingBar.complete();
            }.bind(this));
        }
    };
    return Pin;
})


app.controller('PinCtrl', function($scope, Pin){
    $scope.pins = new Pin();
    $scope.pins.more();
});
</script>
```

urls.py

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from .views import (
    PostListAPIView,
    PostDetailAPIView,
    PostUpdateAPIView,
    PostDeleteAPIView,
    PostCreateAPIView,
    )

from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from .views import PostListView


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', PostListAPIView.as_view(), name='list'),
    url(r'^create/$', PostCreateAPIView.as_view(), name='create'),
    #url(r'^create/$', post_create),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', PostDetailAPIView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/edit/$', PostUpdateAPIView.as_view(), name='update'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/delete/$', PostDetailAPIView.as_view(), name='delete'),

    #url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/edit/$', post_update, name ='update'),
    #url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/delete/$', post_delete),
    #url(r'^posts/$', "<appname>.views.<function_name>"),



    url(r'^$', PostListView.as_view(), name='list2')
]
```

serializers.py

```
        from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer, HyperlinkedIdentityField

    from posts.models import Post


    class PostCreateUpdateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Post
            fields = [
                #'id',
                'title',
                #'slug',
                'content',
                'publish'
            ]


    class PostDetailSerializer(ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Post
            fields = [
                'id',
                'title',
                'slug',
                'content',
                'publish'
                ]


    class PostListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
        url = HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name='posts-api:detail',
        lookup_field='slug'
        )
        delete_url = HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name='posts-api:delete',
        lookup_field='slug'
        )
        class Meta:
            model = Post
            fields = [
                'url',
                'id',
                'title',
                'content',
                'publish',
                'delete_url'
            ]



    from rest_framework import serializers

    class PinSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Post
```

views.py

```
    from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView, ListAPIView, RetrieveAPIView, UpdateAPIView, DestroyAPIView

from posts.models import Post
from .serializers import PostCreateUpdateSerializer, PostListSerializer, PostDetailSerializer

from rest_framework.pagination import LimitOffsetPagination, PageNumberPagination
from .pagination import PostLimitOffsetPagination, PostPageNumberPagination

class PostCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostCreateUpdateSerializer

class PostDetailAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostDetailSerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'

class PostUpdateAPIView(UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostCreateUpdateSerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'

class PostDeleteAPIView(DestroyAPIView):
     queryset = Post.objects.all()
     serializer_class = PostDetailSerializer
     lookup_field = 'slug'

class PostListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostListSerializer
#    pagination_class = PostLimitOffsetPagination

from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework import filters
from rest_framework.pagination import LimitOffsetPagination


from .serializers import PostListSerializer

class PostListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostListSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('category',)
    pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination
```

thanks.

the live site is here : http://192.241.153.25:8000/

Comment: I have a feeling that you are not loading the module correctly. Can you paste in the full error that you see in the console ?

Comment: `{{ variable }}` is a django template construct ... so angular does not see it ... I think you can use a library like triangle to put angular directives in your django templates

Comment: @AminMeyghani live site : http://192.241.153.25:8000/

Comment: @JoranBeasley could you elaborate more on that please?

Comment: The error that your link is currently throwing has to do with missing the sanitize module.  You need to make sure you're including it.  Add a script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-sanitize.js to your code.

Comment: @clockwatcher thanks for that. it solved few of my problems. but im still somehow getting this new error :   Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined. do you happen to know why?  http://192.241.153.25:8000/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first error was the missing sanitize module as I referenced in my comment.  Adding the missing include:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

Will fix that.

Your current error is really a new question but has to do with this code in your index page (line 498 of the rendered index page).

```
$http.get(this.url).success(function(data) {
    var items = data.results;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        this.items.push(items[i]);
}
...
```

The data object that your code is being returned looks like this:

```
    [ {  
      "url":"http://192.241.153.25:8000/api/posts/test-2/",
      "id":3,
      "title":"test",
      "content":"test",
      "publish":"2016-01-01",
      "delete_url":"http://192.241.153.25:8000/api/posts/test-2/delete/"
    },
    ...
    ]
```

It doesn't have a results property.  I didn't really look into what you were doing with it but you probably want this (notice the lack of the "results"):

```
$http.get(this.url).success(function(data) {
    var items = data;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        this.items.push(items[i]);
}
...
```

Or you want to change up what you're returning so that it has a results property.

Comment: Using the  `.success` method is deprecated. You may want to update to include the modern `.then(funtion(...))` notation.

Comment: thanks @clockwatcher. it works. but do you happen to know why the data is rendered as {{ post.title }} instead of real title? i checked the console and the data is showing alright, just the rending seems to be problem. And also, the infinite scrolling itself doesn't seem to work. it only shows initial item, and do not respond to my mouse nor get the additional items. this is all my code : https://gist.github.com/cityproject/52f11458bfc090be08e5e683d137a2c9 i know it's totally last minute, but could you maybe take a look at it? i would love to start a new question, but im blocked currently :p

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div ng-app="myApp" class="app">
    <div ng-controller="appCtrl as vm" class="main-container">
        <h1>Post List</h1>
        {% verbatim %}
        <div ng-repeat="post in vm.posts | limitTo: 10" class="post">
        <a href="{{ post.url}}">
            <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2> <!-- this is django template language and expects a django context variable named post that has an attribute of title -->
            <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
      </a>
            <p ng-if="vm.loadingPosts">Loading...</p>
        </div>
        {% endverbatim %}
    </div>
  </div>
```

instead you must escape your `{{` and `}}` for angular to see them

```
 {% templatetag openvariable %} angular_variable {% templatetag closevariable %}
```

or use something like https://github.com/jrief/django-angular